# Google Cloud MySQL 2nd Generation vs Compute Instance with MySQL

Tags: mysql, google-compute-engine, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-sql

The new Google Cloud MySQL 2nd Generation spins up its own VM instance to run the MySQL server. Please see the following picture:

[image: Instance]

What is the difference between using the 2nd Generation instance, or using my own Compute VM instance with a manually installed version of MySQL on it? Are there any advantages when it comes to high availability, security, or performance?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Adding to the answer that Terry posted, and answering your question in the comment:

You can create a highly available Cloud SQL Second Generation by doing the following:

1. Set up your master instance correctly including sizing it appropriately and setting up binary logging. The master instance must have one backup after binary logging has been enabled. You should place your master instance in a zone that's close to your other services. See [preparing the master instance](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/high-availability#prep).
2. Create one failover replica in a different zone than the master. See [creating a failover replica](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/high-availability#failover).
3. Optionally, create one or more read replicas. Note that a master instance with a failover replica is sufficient for creating a highly available configuration.
4. Optionally, [test failover](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/high-availability#test). Keep in mind that testing the failover moves the master to a new zone.

To answer your question "So what happens if the VM instance they create fails?"

A master instance falls out of high availability mode when the failover replica becomes unavailable. This can happen, for example, if the network connection between the master instance and failover replica is interrupted, or if the failover replica is down due to its own zone failure. During this time, the master instance is not in high availability mode, and you will not be able to failover to the replica because it is not safe to do so. The failover replica resumes replication on reconnection, and high availability mode is re-enabled when the failover replica finishes catching up.

Answer (score 1):

The major difference is that Cloud SQL v2 does not have to be managed.  Google Cloud handles management, replication, and snapshots. Additionally Cloud SQL v2 using [Cloud SQL Proxy](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/sql-proxy) works with App Engine standard and flexible runtimes to allow for flexible, but secure connections to SQL from other clients.

In return you do not have any access to any of the underlying system.

Comment: So what happens if the VM instance they create fails?

Comment: It gets logged and you have the option to restart. Or so I assume, I don't have first hand experience with this particular scenario.

Comment: The managed SQL instances should be restarted for you automatically if there is a software failure. (As George points out.)